# Solving MDP as linear program: why minimize the sum of the states' values?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, bellman-equations, linear-programming

This is a follow-up question to the answer to [How can we use linear programming to solve an MDP?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11251/47897)

Quick recap: the $max$ operators that appear in the Bellman optimality equations can be turned into a set of inequality constraints in hope of making a linear program out of the equation system.

As I understand, we want to minimize the value of **every** $V^*(s)$ independently. So, I would think we would solve as many linear programs as there are states. But the answer linked above rather say to minimize the sum $\sum_{s \in S} V^*(s)$.

I don't understand why this is correct. Is it a property of this very kind of problems? Is it a general property of linear programs?